# Tube terminology for tandems

Tags: tandems, terminology

The names of the tubes are [well established](https://www.bike-advisor.com/getting-to-know-the-frame-tubes-names/) for standard single-rider diamond frames, but seemingly less so for tandems.

For tandems, there's a bit more variety in frame design, but the one I've just bought - for example - has 3 lengthwise tubes plus the downtube: a sloped toptube, a horizontal tube between the 2 bottom brackets ("bottom tube"?) and a third tube in between them (I've no idea what to call that).  all of these meet the head tube together.

[image: Tandem, but what are the tubes called]

The tube in the middle is common but not always used the same way - Dawes, for example,  have the real toptube meet this diagonal tube behind the headtube, so the uppermost tube isn't straight in the front triangle.  Others have a horizontal front toptube and very sloped rear toptube, allowing stepping through the frame.

Is there a standard set of tube names for tandems?

Comment: This answer has a diagram, but does not contain any references or much in the way of discussion or alternative terminologies: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/74186/452

Comment: Meanwhile, [this page](https://www.rodbikes.com/articles/stiff-proposition/stiff-proposition.html) suggests that what's termed the "lateral tube" in the above link can also be called the "stiffener tube".

Comment: @WillVousden I prefer the 2nd - "lateral" seems too much like it should mean a tube going across rather than along.  OTOH "stiffener" is a good description of the purpose, less so if we want to refer a piece of metal.  It establishes "keel tube" though, which I hadn't come across

Comment: I wonder if "lateral" is more to do with the twin-tubes of a mixte, which are often thinner than a single tube.   My post at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/74187/19705  was a bit vague originally, and noone's managed to find a clarification.   Could be the small spreader-tube is the source of "lateral" ?

Comment: @Criggie I think I've seen a tandem with twin tubes similar to that, but I'm not sure if it had a spreader tube. That little tube certainly does run laterally. I guess a nearly-longitudinal tube could be named for providing lateral stiffening, and abbreviated